# IInstrumentationWatcher класс не найден

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

```
public class PdfViewer extends AppCompatActivity{

private String pathToFile;
private PDFView pdfView;
private Integer pageNumber = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_viewer);
    this.pathToFile = getIntent().getStringExtra("pathToFile");
    this.pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
    this.pdfView.fromAsset(this.pathToFile)
            .defaultPage(this.pageNumber)
            .load();
}

}
```

Есть вот такой кусок кода, который должен отобразить содержимое pdf файла в определённый виджет.
[Библиотека для просмотра pdf файлов](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)

Так вот при попытке открыть содержимого вылетала программа, Debug показал что ошибка в классе Instrumentation, в этом же классе он не может найти класс
IInstrumentationWatcher. 
Помогите исправить данную проблему.

Comment: Без стакТрэйса помочь практически невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб его как-то можно вызвать???

Comment: Это то, что выводится в логи при ошибке. Там название ошибки и место её появления, включая номер строки в конкретном файле.